# Can anyone solve this vector and matrix simultaneous equation?

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I want to solve a simltaneous equation below.

$\left(K+\lambda_1I\right)\alpha = \frac{1}{n}\left(y-Ah\right)$

$\left(A^2+\lambda_2I\right)h=A\left(y-nK\alpha\right)$

Here, $n, \lambda_1, \lambda_2>0$ are scalar. $\alpha, h$, and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

$K \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive definite.

I want to solve for $\alpha$ and $h$, fixing other variables.

My answer is $\alpha=\frac{\lambda_2}{n}\left(\lambda_1\left(A^2+\lambda_2I\right)+\lambda_2K\right)^{-1}y$, and $h=\lambda_1 A \left(\lambda_1\left(A^2+\lambda_2I\right)+\lambda_2K\right)^{-1}y$.
Is this correct and unique solution?

Answer (score 2):

Write as

$$\begin{cases}\left(K+\lambda_1I\right)&\alpha+\frac{1}{n}A&h& = \frac{1}{n}y\\
nA^2K&\alpha+\left(A^2+\lambda_2I\right)&h&=Ay\end{cases}$$
which is an ordinary linear system.

If you solve it block-wise, for instance by Gaussian elimination, you will see negative terms appear, so I don't think that your solution is correct.

Comment: I first solve for $\alpha$ and then solver for $h$. Is this procedure wrong?

Comment: @ommc: no, the procedure can work.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\L{\lambda}
\def\Lo{\lambda_1}
\def\Lt{\lambda_2}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
$Multiply the first equation by $nA$ and subtract the second equation to eliminate $y$
$$\eqalign{
Ay &= nA\LR{K+\Lo I} \a &\;+\; \quad\;\;\quad\LR{A^2}h \\
Ay &= \qquad\quad\LR{nAK} \a &\;+\; \LR{A^2+\Lt I}h \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
0 &= n\LR{\Lo A} \a \;-\; \Lt h \qquad\qquad\qquad \\
}$$
Solve for $h$ and substitute into the first equation to obtain a linear system for $\a$
$$\eqalign{
h &= \frac n\Lt\LR{\Lo A} \a \\
M &\doteq n\LR{K+\Lo I} + \frac n\Lt\LR{\Lo A^2} \\
y &= M\a \quad\implies\quad
\a = M^{-1}y \\
}$$
This is different than your proposed solution.

Comment: Sorry. I've miswritten the problem.
The correct second equation is: $\left(A^2+\lambda_2 I \right)h=A\left(y−nK\alpha\right)$.

In this case, your calculation will coincide with mine.